# Помогите пожaлуйста составить sql запрос

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008

В БД есть множество таблиц. В некоторых из них есть колонка NPI. 
Также есть таблица PI_T с колонкой NPI, в которой указано единственное значение, являющиеся эталонным.
Необходимо написать запрос, который выведет имена тех таблиц, в которых в колонке NPI есть значение, отличающиеся от эталонного.

Comment: Что такое "множество таблиц" ? Вы надеюсь понимаете, что SQL требует указания всех участвующих таблиц в запросе. И средств получать этот список как то динамически нет. По хорошему у вас вообще не должно быть "множества таблиц", а должна быть одна таблица с указанием дополнительных полей, указывающих на то, что это за данные

Comment: вы определитесь, вам mysql Или sql-server таки нежун

Comment: Нужен sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно получить список таких объектов, и для каждого из них выполнить запрос. Для таких целей есть хранимая процедура **sp_msforeachtable**, но в данном случае она не подходит, так как запрос нужно выполнить не для каждой таблицы, а только для таблицы с искомым полем, поэтому сформируем список из системной таблицы:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

select  @sql += 'if exists (    select * 
               from    [' + object_schema_name(c.object_id) + '].[' + 
               object_name(c.object_id) + '] as t 
                       left  join PI_T on t.NPI = PI_T.NPI 
               where PI_T.NPI is null) 
    print ''[' + object_schema_name(c.object_id) + '].[' + 
    object_name(c.object_id) + ']'';' + char(13) + char(10)
from    sys.columns as c
where   c.name = 'NPI' and object_name(c.object_id) != 'PI_T '

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: `select *` то зачем?

Comment: @teran, затем, что в условии exists нет необходимости ограничивать число возвращаемых полей - поскольку они не возвращаются - движок только проверяет существование записи. Ранее (ЕМНИП, в 2000 версии и ранее) было хорошим тоном использовать "select 1", но с тех пор обработка таких запросов была оптимизирована, и нет необходимости делать такую оптимизацию в коде.

Comment: @minamoto Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос (с T-SQL плохо знакома): как вывести на экран результат запроса? В нем прописан print, но в итоге на панели выводится только "Command(s) completed successfully".

Comment: Это значит, что у вас нет таких таблиц. Замените exists на not exists - и вам выведется ровно противоположный список - все таблицы с таким полем, в которых нет значений, отличающихся от эталонного, чтобы проверить работоспособность скрипта (и то, что вы его на нужной базе вообще выполняете).

Comment: @minamoto Всё, поняла. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @minamoto а могли бы вы мне пожалуйста подсказать еще одну вещь: можно ли этот запрос адресовать на все БД на сервере сразу? Пробовала sp_MSForEachDB вместо sp_executesql, но таблицы он не находит (а они точно есть)

Comment: Правильно пробовали, но нужно грамотно расставить кавычки и в самом начале скрипта добавить "USE ?;", чтобы скрипт выполнялся в контексте каждой базы, а не в контексте базы, из которой вы его выполняете.